# pressing on notification opens the same activity twice

Tags: android, android-activity, google-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent

If i have an activity that closed by a user (user pressed on home so the app is still in app stack)
and then he gets a notification, when he presses on it i start an activity 
and now the same activity is opened twice.
How can i prevent this from happening?

My CODE:

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, 
        new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
        this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setLights(GCMSIntentService.PURPLE, 500, 500)
            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
            .setContentText(msg);

mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: u can use  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY );

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

in manifest Or, 
use it as flag for your intent.

Comment: is there a way to make the re started activity to be recreated? onCreate should be called

Comment: Restart, you can post intent through notification and handle in onNewIntent method, and then act based on the new intent (in your case refresh)

Answer (score 1):

by `android:launchMode="singleTask"`, if an instance of the activity already exists in a separate task, the system routes the intent to the existing instance through a call to its `onNewIntent()` method, rather than creating a new instance  and adding flags to the intent

FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK,FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP,FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP

refer [task and back stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

Comment: is there a way to make the re started activity to be recreated? onCreate should be called

Comment: You could just move whatever code is in onCreate to onResume. That would account for creates and resumes as well. Refer to [this chart](http://developer.android.com/images/training/basics/basic-lifecycle.png).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP),[FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP),[FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)   flags to your notification intent.So change

```
 PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

to

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);


PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent , PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the error.

notify functions id has to be changed everytime. You're giving it 1 everytime. thats the error.

mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

give a different id everytime. it will work like a charm.

For example, use sharedPrefences to provide different id's everytime.

check this,

```
     PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                    this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                            .setContentTitle("Title")
                            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                    .bigText(msg))
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setLights(GCMSIntentService.PURPLE, 500, 500)
                            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                            .setContentText(msg);

            mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

 SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences("randomidfornotification", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        myIntValue = sp.getInt("notificationid", 0);

mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

SharedPreferences sp1 = context.getSharedPreferences("randomidfornotification", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp1.edit();
        editor.putInt("notificationid", myIntValue+1);
        editor.apply();
```